# Architecture of MVC application without using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, design-patterns, architecture

I am new in MVC application development.I am willing to develop a new project using MVC, i looked a lot for architectures that suits to MVC application.
After reading many articles and blogs i came to know that repository pattern can be used for this.
Based on my understanding before starting real project i created a dummy project structure like described below [ Not using EDMX file, entity framework in project, defined custom DAL ]

Name of my dummy application is Repository.I took Country,state and city relationship as example to develop dummy application :

**Repository_DAL_V1** *class library* This library has class as below :
    SQLHelper.cs : This class have methods to get executed for queries like ExecutenonQuery etc.

**Repository_DTO_V1** *class library* This library has class as below :
    CountryDTO.cs : This class is inherited from CountryModel.cs as [ CountryDTO:CountryModel ].This will be used to move data between all layers of application.If there is any property that is supposed to be used in business then this will be created in DTO not in model.
    CountryDTOMapper.cs : This is used to map data from database in form of DataTable into collection of DTO object.

**Repository_Implementation** *web mvc project* This is UI Layer.

**Repository_IRepositories_V1** *class library* This library has class as below :
    ICountryRepository.cs : This is a interface having declared functions like SaveCountry() etc.

**Repository_Models** *class library* This library has class as below :
    CountryModel.cs : This class has properties exactly for all columns of table in database.

**Repository_Repositories_V1** *class library* This library has class as below :
    CountryRepository.cs : This is a repository class having defined functions like SaveCountry() etc.

**Repository_ViewModel_V1** *class library* This library has class as below :
    CountryViewModel.cs : This will be build for Country View on screen.

above projects reference details :

Repository_DTO_V1 has reference of Repository_Models.
Repository_IRepositories_V1 has reference of Repository_DTO_V1,Repository_Models.
Repository_Repositories_V1 has reference of Repository_IRepositories_V1,Repository_DAL_V1,Repository_DTO_V1,Repository_Models.
Repository_ViewModel_V1 has reference of Repository_Repositories_V1,Repository_IRepositories_V1,Repository_DTO_V1,Repository_Models.

I need guidence from all of you to steer me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't se why not using EF would be any different from any other project you done layer wise that is. There is nothing wrong with you structure of things if you are comftable with using mulitple layers. I don't know what your project is about but you should consider better naming, like Project name (Repository) and Implementations is better named Web.

**EDIT**
I recommend you to use Entity Framework 5 with Code First, that is if you want to use a ORM?

Comment: Thanks for reply.i posted my idea with dummy example that's why name is like repository. And i don`t want to use EDMX file because my database may get changed in that case if i refresh EDMX file then it can overwrite my changes done in associated class.

Comment: Using EF, I recommend you to use EF code first approach instead of EDMX generated file, that gives you the liberty of changing the model class as you please. But my main point was that the layer structure does not have so much to do with using EF, NHibernate or pure SQL. Performance would be in the sql you write or how you setup EF or NHibernate more then layer abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly with you on the desire to give EF a miss.

As @Dejan.S says, The architecture you'll need depends on the size of your project.

I would start off simple, perhaps with 3 projects:

- A web project.
- A service project that controllers use to access models and business logic.
- A domain project with your models and data access.

If you need to separate things (like a DAL), you can still do that later.

Also, check out ServiceStack's [MVC Power Pack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/). You get a great micro ORM, IoC, caching, fast serialisers and so on out of the box.

Comment: Size of project is very big as in database some tables having rows around 28000 so performance is also to be taken into count.

Comment: @GauravRajput The size of the project is more of the tables then rows, I currently work on a project that got 100's of thousands of rows but only 5 tables, so project wise its small

Comment: Also 28k is a very small table volume :)

Comment: @Dejan.S I agree with you, i was just trying to add more information about volume of data to/from database. Anyway my database consists of tables 385.